# OCR a written angle in a wind rose

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tesseract, python-tesseract

I`m working with OCR to get some values in an PDF, i had success to get text in other parts of pdf, but i was not able to extract the angled text on this image(its a wind rose with annotated text), there are different pdfs with different angles, as on this images:

[It should be converted to 250](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Czf.png)

[It should be converted to 330](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVt3P.png)

I've tried pytesseract with image_to_osd, but without success.

Comment: Can you explain the angles in your two images? One seems to be counted clockwise, the other counter-clockwise!? Also, the values don't seem to be correct. 330° should be more something like 340°. My idea was to use `HoughLines` to identify the line indicating the angle, and then rotate the image. But, therefore it's necessary to have information about the rotation direction and proper angles.

Comment: Oh, thats a good idea! but answering your question, these are extracted from geological stuff, and the wind rose angles start from N (0/360 degrees) and clockwise.

Comment: Ok, then the caption for the 250° image is wrong, isn't it? According to you description and the 330° image, the angle should be something 200°!? Do you have some additional images to work on? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67469050/edit) your question, and add them.

Comment: I've just got what you mean, yeah its not exactly correct, the wind rose is for reference( it just match the quadrant, but not exactly the angle).
All my examples are with 250 and 330 :/ but i will get more with other angles.